# Can I reference locations using getExternalStorageDirectory() on a Nexus S?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, nexus-s

I'm developing software based on an open source package that uses external storage to archive data. I wanted to get a Nexus S to help me develop this software, but just noticed that it doesn't have an SD card slot!

I've seen that some other Android phones without SD slots just have a /mnt/sdcard directory as though there were external storage, but others apparently don't offer this feature.

So does the Nexus S emulate external storage? Or will this phone break my code...?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not get any problems:

> **Note:** don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it **may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device** that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

*From the [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).*

Answer (score 1):

So far i never experienced any problem with my apps at my Samsung Galaxy S internal "SD" like storage using the getExternalStorageDirectory(). The phones are identical so I believe you will not have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have a Nexus S and I can confirm that this works.